# Access report with uniqe values between dates

Tags: ms-access

I want to create an Access report where in a form, the user enters "Start Date" and "End Date" and the report will show the unique values of Departments and Courses between those dates.

I created a query and for the date field I created a parameter like :

```
Between [Forms]![frmReports_Menu]![txtStartDate] And [Forms]![frmReports_Menu]![txtEndDate]
```

Query SQL is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department, Course, DoneDate
FROM TrainingsDone INNER JOIN Trainings ON TrainingsDone.TrgMastID = Trainings.TrgMastID
WHERE (((TrainingsDone.DoneDate) Between [Forms]![frmReports_Menu]![txtStartDate] And [Forms]![frmReports_Menu]![txtEndDate]));
```

The problem is when you show the Dates in the report it does not become Unique values for the Department and Courses, because it will show multiple dates.

I can't use a "WhereCondition" when opening the report with `DoCmd.OpenReport` because I can't include DoneDate in the query for values to be Unique.

How can I create the query and assign parameters to get the unique Department and Course list within a date range taken as parameters from the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using *Group By*:

```sql
SELECT 
    Department, Course
FROM 
    TrainingsDone 
INNER JOIN 
    Trainings 
    ON TrainingsDone.TrgMastID = Trainings.TrgMastID
WHERE 
    TrainingsDone.DoneDate 
        Between [Forms]![frmReports_Menu]![txtStartDate] 
        And [Forms]![frmReports_Menu]![txtEndDate]
GROUP BY
    Department, Course
```

Comment: The problem is when I run the Query while the form is open and the 2 date parameters are populated it runs correctly, but I use this query as  a record source for a Report and when I run the report it pop-ups "Enter Parameter" DoneDate, which I don't understand why

Comment: Yes. It can't, of course, fetch the values if the form is closed. If so, parameter values must be passed in some other way. One method it to use TempVars.

Comment: The form is not closed, there is a button on the form which contains the "start date" and "end date" parameters and a button which opens the report with "DoCmd.OpenReport "reportName", acViewPreview", so the form is open but I still got the error

Comment: So the report runs with your original query but not with mine? That is weird.

Comment: No, the query runs if I run it by double-clicking the query (or running it when the query is open) without asking the parameter if the form is open. However, when I run the report whose record source is the query it asks for the parameter even if the form is open. This is the main problem here, not redesigning the query but preventing the report from asking for the parameter

Comment: Does it ask for `DoneDate` or the form's textbox values?

Comment: It asks for DoneDate, not the form's textbox values

Comment: Of course. The report expects this field which is now excluded. Remove the control that has `DoneDate` as control source.

Comment: Yes, now that solved the issue, thank you